# I installed Ubuntu along with my windows10 and WANT TO REMOVE UBUNTU

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu

How do I uninstall Ubuntu as well as its Boot manager, in my Lenovo computer. I don’t have Windows Recovery Disc since Lenovo have their own "One Key recovery"?

Just now,I created a backup "ISO"file of my windows OS into my personal Hard drive( in case something worse happens).

My question is how do I remove Ubuntu completely without affecting my windows partitions?

Thanks

Comment: You go to M$ forums and ask them to add support to other OSs

Answer (score 1):

you could download windows on USB drive and use it as installation source.  you need to choose repair option(this step will remove the ubuntu mbr). 
once it's done you need to get back the disk space used by Ubuntu 
you need to to go to disc manager and erase disc space allocated for Ubuntu and format it as ntfs.

Comment: If i reset my laptop will my Ubuntu boot manager gone, and will i be able to use my backup ISO file to get my windows stuff back? at the same time, boot manager will be gone and when i boot, will i have windows boot manager?

Comment: if you reset your computer you ll lose everything and you ll get your computer as it s new !

Comment: since i made a complete backup ISO File of my windows OS, docs and everything?? will it work?? Im kinda new to this

Comment: it should work but but it will take a lot of time .

Comment: Ok,, thank you for lettting  me know its time consuming, is there a easier to way to get rid of ubuntu and its boot manager?? easily?

Comment: i already answered that ;)

Comment: Thank You,,,, Manage to get my windows back,,, Everything is FINE...THanks to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Download [Dual-boot Repair tool](https://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html).

Extract zip file to an empty directory, application is portable, and create a shortcut icon for the tool on Desktop.

Clicking on `Automatic Repair` displays a list of all installed Windows versions and fixes the booting to latest Windows OS on your computer.

Once it's done. Go to disc manager and erase disc space allocated for Ubuntu and format it as NTFS.